# Compiler changes the type variable type from uin16_t to int when it's marked as constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr

I've encountered a weird problem trying to flip all bits of my number.

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr uint16_t DefaultValueForPortStatus { 0xFFFF };

void f(uint16_t x)
{

}

int main()
{
  f(~(DefaultValueForPortStatus));
}
```

When I'm compiling this program (GCC trunk) I'm getting an error:

> warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '-65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]

When I remove constexpr from type specifier, then no warning appears.
Why is that? Why does the uint16_t constexpr variable is being changed by the compiler to int, whereas in the case of non-constexpr everything is fine?

Comment: Doesn't bit negate `~` do a promotion to `int` for smaller types?

Comment: "Compiler changes the type variable type from uin16_t to int when it's marked as constexpr" --> The change in `~(DefaultValueForPortStatus)`   from type `uint16_t` to `int` is not dependent on `constexpr`.

Comment: I would argue that in general this is a reason to use the XOR operator rather than the not operator, so you control how many bits are inverted rather than leaving it up to C's counter-intuitive promotion rules,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is caused by IMHO a quite unfortunate C++ rule about integer promotion. It basically states that all types smaller than `int` are always promoted to `int` if `int` can represent all values of the original type. Only if not, `unsigned int` is chosen. `std::uint16_t` on standard 32/64-bit architectures falls into the first category.

`int` is guaranteed to be at least 16-bit wide, if that would happen to be the case, `unsigned int` would have been chosen, **so the behaviour of the code is implementation-defined.**

I do not know precisely why the compiler issues the warning only for `constexpr` values, most likely because it could easily propagate that constant through the `~`. In other cases, someone might change `DefaultValueForPortStatus` to some "safe" value that won't overflow when negated and converted from `int` back to `std::uint16_t`. But the issue is there regardless of constness, you can test it with this code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

constexpr uint16_t DefaultValueForPortStatus { 0xFFFF };

int main()
{
  auto x = ~(DefaultValueForPortStatus);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int>);
}
```

Relevant Standard sections:

- [expr.conv.prom-7.3.7](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom) - The first few paragraphs.
- [expr.unary.op-7.6.2.2.10](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#10) - The last paragraph, states that "Integer promotion" is applied.
- [expr.arith.conv-7.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv) - Only applies for binary operators, still contains similar rules.

Comment: Yeah, almost certainly because of constant-propagation or lack thereof, meaning GCC wouldn't see that specific value being truncated during compile-time eval.  You'd see the same thing with `static` instead of `constexpr`, because that would let it see that no other code in this translation unit changes the var and thus it's a compile time constant.  Without either, it has no reason to assume that the global var still has the value it was statically initialized with when that part of `main` executes.  (A static constructor in another TU could have changed it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Actually, `static` is [apparently](https://godbolt.org/z/a5no4bfxW) not enough even though the compilers have no trouble optimizing through it (and truncating the return value to 0). `const` works. Maybe the warnings run before non-`const` optimizations? Not sure. But nice note about other TUs changing the value, I did not think about that at all.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised.  Maybe has something to do with not warning for `return (uint16_t)~((uint16_t)0xFFBB)` or `return (uint16_t)~DefaultValueForPortStatus` either.  Like only when it thinks you really intended it to be const, not all cases where it happens to be able to do constant-propagation.  And also not cases where the constant is right there in the expression for you to see?  gcc and clang seem to agree on whether to warn or not (https://godbolt.org/z/f7x8onP17) even with `-Wall -pedantic -Wextra -fsanitize=undefined` (this isn't UB so not surprising that UBsan didn't do anything).

Comment: @PeterCordes I kind of understand `return (uint16_t)~((uint16_t)0xFFFF);` not generating any warnings, you explicitly cast it. `uint16_t foo(){return ~((uint16_t)0xFFFF); }` generates the warning. I just noticed the warning is called `-Wconstant-conversion` in clang, that might also explain it :D

Answer (score 7):

Due to [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion), on platforms on which `int` is 32 bits, the expression

`~(DefaultValueForPortStatus)`

evaluates to an `int` with the value `-65536`.

What exactly happens is the following:

Before the bitwise-NOT (`~`) operation takes place, the operand `DefaultValueForPortStatus` gets promoted to an `int`, so that its memory representation will be equivalent to that of an `unsigned int` with the following value:

`0x0000FFFF`

After applying the bitwise-NOT (`~`) operator to it, its memory representation will be equivalent to that of an `unsigned int` with the following value:

`0xFFFF0000`

However, the result has the data type `int`, not `unsigned int`. (I am only using the equivalent values of `unsigned int` for illustrating the memory representation.) Therefore, the actual value of the result is `-65536` (because C++ requires that [two's complement memory representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is used for signed integers).

When converting this `int` to `uint16_t` to match the type of the function parameter, the 16 [most significant bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) are discarded and the 16 least significant bits are preserved. Therefore, the function argument will have the value `0`.

When compiling using default settings, gcc provides a warning of such truncations, if they occur in a constant expression. This warning can be disabled with the `-Wno-overflow` command line option.

The reason why the compiler warns by default is probably because it assumes that such truncations are not intended to occur in constant expressions. It does not make this assumption with expressions that are based on non-`const` variables.

The truncation will occur either way, whether the compiler issues a warning or not.